# Getting issue while importing product data in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: importexport, magento2.4.1

We are looking for solution in Magento 2.4.1 which can resolve our issue in data import

In our case the category name are like

Available Brands Migrated/Kitchen, Storage & Furniture/Cookware/Baking & Roasting Trays

So in this case Kitchen, Storage & Furniture is a single category but Magento taking it a comma separate making kitchen and Storage & Furniture as separate category. So does anybody have faced similar issue. The problem is that in CSV everything is comma separated but if category name have comma then how can we resolve this case.

Comment: Have you tried using double-quotes to enclose the CSV values? This is generally how commas within values are handled in CSV formatted data: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2 (2-6)

Comment: Actually, It looks like the issue here is that Magento expects comma-separated values *within comma-separated values*. If so, the spec won't help.

Comment: Not so sure but you can try to escape it with `\ `   As workaround, just replace it with something else in csv (for example `;`) and replace it after import.